# opera is proxifying all my stuff, why?

Tags: osx-leopard, opera

i thought just opera-mini was supposed to send all the requests through the norway proxy servers but when I open up opera browser (latest release) on mac osx, i get everything sent through the norway proxies. I guess this does have its uses, but should this be the default behavior? I am posting this from a different browser, but as I type this I am getting strange behavior from opera like being redirected to the opera unite home. I havent used this browser in a month or so, have there just been  a lot of changes or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review your config of Opera Turbo. By default is automatic.

[image: Config Opera Turbo]